# Integration on Differential Forms.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

So I know that divergence and curl of a vector field $F$ can be related to a differential form $\alpha$ by div $ F = \star  d \star \alpha$ and curl $ \cdot F = \star d \alpha $ , where $\star$ is the hodge star operator and d is the exterior derivative operator. So these two operators unify and extend to arbitrary dimensions the classical differential operators of vector calculus. I was wondering if there are any similar physical interpretations or applications of integrating differential forms such as $\int \alpha $ ? It could involve integrating differential forms after applying the above two operators. Is integrating differential forms purely an abstract concept unlike applying the hodgestar or exterior derivative operators on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not. If you're thinking of the $1$-form $\alpha$ as corresponding to a vector field $\vec F$, integrating $\alpha$ along a curve gives you the work done by $\vec F$ along that curve. Similarly, integrating the $2$-form $\star\alpha$ over an oriented surface in $\Bbb R^3$ gives the flux of $\vec F$ across that surface.

(You might find some of my [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) useful. In particular, look at 3510 days 30 through 39, and 41-42 for some of these 3D connections and applications.)